# How to run Timer Repeatedly in Background && Suspend iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, location

I am new to iOS developement and How can i Run timer Repeatedly(To call function) in Background && Suspend ?

I want to Run Timer Repeatedly,Then I can Get the user current location Repeatedly.
Also is there any other method to get user current location using notification or Timer.

Comment: This might be help full https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/69152

Comment: Do you want user's location while app is launched? Please share your requirement clearly.

Comment: @teja_D Yes, I want user's location all state(active, background, suspend).

Comment: You can't use a Timer and you don't need to. If your app has "always" location permission and you have enabled background location the location updates will be delivered to your app.

Comment: @Paulw11, is that any example/ sample code for doing this scenario? I tried some of the things, but these aren't work in suspend state.

Comment: @ThushalMadhushanka What do you mean by suspend state?

Comment: @teja_D when the user kills the app.

Comment: @ThushalMadhushanka it is not possible to get user's location after killing the app

Comment: FYI you are referring to the terminated state, not the suspended state. In the terminated state you app is not running and cannot get updates. The app states are foreground->background->suspended. From the suspended state it can return to executing in the background, executing in the foreground or it can be terminated by iOS (due to needing memory) or terminated by the user by swiping away. You can use significant location change to relaunch from the terminated state

Answer (score 0):

> The significant location change service delivers events normally while
> an app is running in the foreground or background. For a terminated
> iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events. Use of
> this service requires “Always” authorization from the user.
>
> The region monitoring service delivers events normally while an app is
> running in the foreground or background. (You can use this service for
> both geographic and beacon regions.) For a terminated iOS app, this
> service relaunches the app to deliver events. Use of this service
> requires “Always” authorization from the user.

Read this apple's documentation -
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW73

If you want user's location in active and background state you need to do following

> Select your project using the project navigator, then find your app’s
> target and choose the Capabilities tab. You need to enable Background
> Modes, then check the box marked “Location updates”.

Please keep in mind that you can get user's location in background mode only when user allow your app to access device's location **Always**

Here is very nice article on how to get user's location seamlessly while app is in active and back

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/location/how-to-read-the-users-location-while-your-app-is-in-the-background